# SublimeGDB: No symbol table is loaded

Tags: debugging, gdb, sublimetext2

I got a problem setting up sublimegdb. I always getting the error message:

"No symbol table is loaded.  Use the \"file\" command."

There seems to be something wrong with my user settings:

```
{
    "workingdir": "/home/name/workspace/project",

    "commandline": "gdb --interpreter=mi ./main" 
}
```

It seems to be a super stupid and easy to solve problem, but i just dont get it...

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

------**SOLVED**------

I justed missed to change my build system and forget to add the parameter -g for debugging to the gcc.

**My Project Settings**

```
 {
"settings":
     {
          "sublimegdb_workingdir": "${folder:${file}}",

          "sublimegdb_arguments": "",

          "sublimegdb_commandline": "gdb --interpreter=mi --args ./${file_base_name}"
     }
}
```

**C Build System**

```
 {
"cmd" : ["gcc -g $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell": true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```